# Observable.zip does not call subscribe.next if sources are given as array

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a two dimentional array of `BehaviorSubject<number>s`. For debugging purposes I want to write the values in a formatted manner as soon as all the array cells emit value. So I wrote this:

```
    Observable.zip(universe.map(row => Observable.zip(row)))
        .takeUntil(stopper)
        .subscribe(u =>
            console.log(`[\n\t[${u.map(r => r.toString()).join("],\n\t[")}]\n]`))
```

Nothing written. And also this hasn't work:

```
    Observable.zip(universe[0])
        .takeUntil(stopper)
        .subscribe(u => console.log(`1[${u.toString()}]`))
```

But these following worked (the array has 5 columns):

```
    Observable.zip(universe[0][0], universe[0][1], universe[0][2], universe[0][3], universe[0][4])
        .takeUntil(stopper)
        .subscribe(u => console.log(`2[${u.toString()}]`))

    Observable.zip(Observable.zip(Observable.zip(Observable.zip(universe[0][0], universe[0][1]), universe[0][2]), universe[0][3]), universe[0][4])
        .takeUntil(stopper)
        .subscribe(u => console.log(`3[${u.toString()}]`))
```

Also I have considered .zipAll() operator but there is no document about it.

This may be a bug in Observable.zip() code as it shows `ArrayLike<BehaviorSubject<number>>` as possible argument type in code assistance.

So is there any other way to get this functionality? How can I get the array values written down once all of the values are reassigned, without knowing the actual dimensions of course?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important thing is that [`zip()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) operator doesn't take an array of Observables but an unpacked series of Observables instead.

That's why `Observable.zip([obs1, obs2, obs3])` doesn't work.

But `Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3)` works.

It's not possible to help you when we don't know what `universe` is. From what you have now it seems like you could use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (assuming you're using ES6 or TypeScript):

```
Observable.zip(...universe[0]);
```

I don't know what plans are with [`zipAll()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/zipAll.js.html#lineNumber8) but right now it just callls `zip()`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt anwer. The definition for univer is this: `let universe: BehaviorSubject<number>[][]`. There is not any compilation or runtime errors regarding the wrong argument. I'll try to use apply() or call() which ever siuts my needs.

Comment: I have founds this in zip.d.ts: `export declare function zipStatic<T>(array: ObservableInput<T>[]): Observable<T[]>`

Comment: @koducu Actually you should worry only about `zipProto` as you can see here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/operator/zip.ts and here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/zip.ts#L13

Comment: You are right but in code assistance window in the editor I saw the function declarations and naturally assume that the function accepts array of `Observable`s. If we can not rely on the official declarations what else then? Should we read all the library code we reference to? Either the zip() should accept `Observable` array or that declarations should be removed from the library in my opinion. Thanks for leading me the right direction.

Comment: AAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH.

(thank you so very much for this answer, I can't believe I spent three hours debugging this just now only to find this)

Answer (score 2):

As of rxjs@5.0.3 Observable.zip() function implementation does not recognize `Observable` arrays even though `export declare function zipStatic<T>(array: ObservableInput<T>[]): Observable<T[]>;` and `export declare function zipStatic<T>(...observables: Array<ObservableInput<T>>): Observable<T[]>;` function declarations take place in rxjs/operator.zip.d.ts (What is the difference between this declarations is beyond my Type/Javascript knowledge). It simply pumps the argument object members passed to it to a local array and never flattens them if you pass array. And even does not check parameter types to raise the situation.

After receiving @martin's answer above, I changed the calls to `Observable.zip()` with `Observable.zip.apply(null, observable_array)` then the problem is solved. But `.zip()` should accept (at least one) array of `Observable`s in order to help readability and adhere to aforementioned function declarations.

Comment: thanks for the "Observable.zip.apply(null, observable_array)" tip!